# Differentiating with respect to x with y in the equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question asks:

find $\dfrac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm dx}$ of $x^2y+xy^2$

I am unsure on what to do about the $y$ in the expression

Thanks.

Comment: You can't compute rate of change of one variable w.r.t. other variable from an expression, it has to be an equation that relates those variables(or implies that they are independent)

Comment: Do you mean ${\partial \over \partial x}$ (since you only give an expression rather than an equation)?

Comment: well the question says dy/dx

Comment: Is the equation equal to some constant?

Comment: The expression - the whole problem is that it is not an equation :) @Inceptio

Comment: Alright broda! If the rate of change does exists, the expression equals some constant right?

Comment: If the question  asked you explicitly to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, then you were probably told that $x^2y+xy^2=17$, or $x^2y+xy^2=x^{17}$, or something like that. The expression "find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $x^2y+xy^2$" doesn't make sense, so is unlikely to be what you were asked to do.

Comment: This is called [Implicit Differentiation](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&cp=8&gs_id=s&xhr=t&q=implicit+differentiation&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=implict+&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.aWc&fp=83725e35ebc0a2f0&biw=1030&bih=684).

Comment: It that *literally* what the question asks, or have you reworded it? If you have reworded it, please post the original wording.

Comment: its is literally what the question asls

Comment: Then unfortunately, before you can do the math problem, you must first solve the riddle "What question did your book *mean* to ask?"

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you had to find $dy/dx$, where, for example, $x^2y+xy^2=7.$ Then you could take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$:

$\frac d{dx}(x^2y+xy^2)=\frac d{dx}7.$

This means that $\frac d{dx}(x^2y+xy^2)=0.$

Now, since you are interested in changes in $x$ you treat $y$ as an unknown function of $x$ and use the chain rule (and in this case the product rule):

$2xy + (dy/dx)x^2+y^2+2xy(dy/dx)=0.$

So that $(dy/dx)(x^2+2xy)=-2xy-y^2$ and so $dy/dx=(-2xy-y^2)/(x^2+2xy).$

This is called implicit differentiation. It is just the chain rule applied to an implied function of $x$ but, as has been mentioned in the comments, we need an equation to make it an implied function of $x$.